# Keeping track of maximum and minimum of integers entered by the user

Tags: java, for-loop, integer, max, min

**Solved**

I want to ask the user how many integers he wants to enter and then read all the numbers whilst keeping track of the maximum and minimum number they entered. Then print the maximum and minimum numbers.

I was thinking of setting the maximum and minimum to the first entered number, then read the next numbers in a for loop and change the maximum and minimum with a bigger/smaller number.
However, it's printing only the first number entered by the user. Can somebody help me out with this? Thank you.

Code:

```
System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to type? ");
int n = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
int number = scanner.nextInt();
int currentMax = number;
int currentMin = number;

for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
  System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
  int nextNumber = scanner.nextInt();

  if (nextNumber > currentMax) {
    currentMax = nextNumber;
  }
  if (nextNumber < currentMin) {
    currentMin = nextNumber;
  }
}
System.out.println(currentMax);
System.out.println(currentMin);
```

Comment: what is value of `n`?

Comment: assuming `n` should be `number`, you still need to do `i <= n-1`

Comment: n is the number of integers the user wants to enter forgot to add that part ill add it

Comment: Also, your logic for finding `currentMax` and `currentMin` is incorrect. If `nextNumber = 7` and `currentMax = 5` then `currentMax = nextNumber`; Same goes for `currentMin`.

Comment: Use `nextNumber` instead of `number`.

Comment: "This is probably because java is statically typed (?)" That's quite a claim. Why do you think static typing has anything do do with this?

Comment: oh i didn't notice that error, i changed it and it works now! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic of checking max and min number is correct, however assigning is incorrect

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
  System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
  int nextNumber = scanner.nextInt();

  if (nextNumber > currentMax) {
    //currentMax = number;  // here its always assigns number as current max as opposed to  nextNumber
      currentMax = nextNumber;
  }
  if (nextNumber < currentMin) {
    //currentMin = number; // here its always assign number as current minas opposed to  nextNumber
currentMin = nextNumber ;
  }
```